# init method with a object from another module

Tags: python, tkinter

```
class tkinter_toggle_button():
    def __init__(self):
        self.button = tk.Button(text="Toggle", width=12, relief="raised")
    def MakeCommand(self):
        print('1')
        if self('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
            button.config(relief="raised")
        else:
            button.config(relief="sunken")
    def MakeButtonToggle(self):
        print('2')
        toggle_btn = tk.Button(text="Toggle", width=12, relief="raised", command=tkinter_toggle_button.MakeCommand)
        return toggle_btn

class UI:
    def MainWindow():
        main_window = tk.Tk()
        togglebutton1 = tkinter_toggle_button()
        togglebutton = togglebutton1.MakeButtonToggle()
        togglebutton.grid(row=0,column=0)
        main_window.mainloop()

UI.MainWindow()
```

I wanted this code to make a toggle button using the init method. I need help understanding the init method with other modules. Was this the right approach. The out put of this code is:

```
2
```

After I press the button:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: MakeCommand() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: At first glance, `button.config` should be `self.button.config`

Comment: You are invoking `MakeCommand()` on the class itself, rather than the instance of the class.  Only the instance has the `self.button` attribute holding the button you want to operate on.

Comment: there is good rule to use UpperCaseNames for classes - ie. `class TkinterToggleButton()` like `tk.Button`, `tk.Label`, etc.  - and lower_case_names for methods - ie. `def make_button_toggle()` like `def __init__`. It makes code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of what you were trying to do.
The class should reference internal variables using `self.`.

```
import Tkinter

class tkinter_toggle_button():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(master, text="Toggle", width=12, relief="raised", command=self.MakeCommand)
    def MakeCommand(self):
        if self.button.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
            self.button.config(relief='raised')
        else:
            self.button.config(relief='sunken')

class UI:
    def MainWindow(self):
        main_window = Tkinter.Tk()
        togglebutton = tkinter_toggle_button(main_window)
        togglebutton.button.grid(row=0,column=0)
        main_window.mainloop()

ui = UI()
ui.MainWindow()
```

Comment: What does the `master` variable do?  Why does the self have to be put in `MainWindow`?

Comment: @JuanRamos the Button class has to have a parent widget as its first argument. So I pass `main_window`, which is taken in as `master` inside of the class and used for the Button. More here: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button-class